# client event on iphone is not working on morris bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, morris.js

```
 <div class="chart chart-md" id="morrisStacked"> </div>              
 <script type="text/javascript">               
 $(document).ready(function () {      
        ajxCall = $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",       
                        url: "/Graph/GetBarData?Inst=" + Inst + "&TimeType=" + TimeType + "&time=" + time + "&AddSub=" + AddSubM + "&Inverters=" + InvList + "&InvId=" + InvId+"&DayEnergy="+estimate,      // Location of the service
                        data: "",       //Data sent to server
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",   //Expected data format from server
                        success: function (result) {  //On Successful service call
                            Loader(false);
                            if (AddSub == 0) {
                                _Chart = Morris.Bar({
                                    resize: true,
                                    element: 'morrisStacked',
                                    data: result[0].data,
                                    ymax: result[0].Ymax,
                                    xkey: 'y',
                                    ykeys: result[0].ykeys,
                                    labels: result[0].labels,
                                    barColors: ['#0088cc', '#2baab1', '#8CC9E8', '#aa88cc', '#aaaab1', '#aaC9E8', '#bb88cc', '#bbaab1', '#bbC9E8', '#cc88cc', '#ccaab1', '#ccC9E8'],
                                    fillOpacity: 0.7,
                                    smooth: false,
                                    stacked: document.getElementById("allInv").checked,
                                    hideHover: true,
                                    yLabelFormat: formatY,
                                    hoverCallback: function (index, options, content, row) {
                                        return content + "<div class='morris-hover-point' style='color:orange'>Forventet:" + formatY(row.Forventet) + "</div>";
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else {
                                _Chart.options["ymax"]=result[0].Ymax;
                                _Chart.setData(result[0].data);
                            }

Chart.on('click', function (i, row) {alert(row.y)  })}</script>
```

i'm using morris chart in my application.i want to perform some action when user click on bar in the graph.
click event is working fine on chrome,firefox,safari browser but i don't why click event is not working on iphone.i'm stuck please help me !.

Answer (score 0):

Even I came across the same problem.

In the iPhone, `Hover` is considered as a click so disable the tooltip by setting `HideHover: "always"` works fine for me.